How do I show the power source switches from binding post to batteries on a schematic?
I'm making a circuit diagram for a friend, and she wants me to draw that the Gopros on her project switch from a DC power supply using binding posts (positive and negative terminals) to a 12V battery pack after you unplug it.
I'm not sure how to show two power sources switching, so temporarily, I'm using a switch footprint that I'm already using in my schematic to show it. Is there a better method to indicate this?
For the binding post, I just used a terminal footprint I found and labeled it 12V+ and 12V- I know for sure that looks wonky af. Can I just use a DC voltage symbol in the third picture to represent the binding post, or is there a specific symbol I can use like the second picture?

is this on Eagle? i cant find the the name for it


Is the switchover electrical or mechanical? Does she know more details on how this works? It’s possible the sources are diode-ORed together and if that’s the case you should show that on your schematic.

Your schematic shows the external power supply shorted: positive and negative terminals connected together.  The negative terminal of the external source should be connected to the battery negative.

@PeterBennett sorry i made that half asleep, i updated the photo, does that look better?

@SteKulov mechanical i guess? she's physically removing the power cables then connecting the batteries with clips

No - you have now connected the +12 V input to Ground.  You should show the negative side of the external source connected to the battery negative.

So there is no actual switch?  The user just transfers a pair of clip leads between the battery and external power?  In that case, I wouldn't show a switch - I'm not sure how I'd document the system.  If you're not making a PC board for this, you may document it however makes sense to you and the user.

@PeterBennett it's just a circuit diagram, no PCB. I also updated it. lmk if it looks right now!

Thanks for the clarifications.

the schematic symbol for a terminal is a plain circle.

Generally, a circuit diagram shows what the components in a circuit are, not what they do. Strictly speaking, there's no way to show that "the power source switches from binding post to batteries" in a circuit diagram, because circuit diagrams simply don't contain that information.
You mentioned in a comment that the way that the switching happens is that

she's physically removing the power cables then connecting the batteries with clips

You should indicate this by simply drawing whatever components your circuit contains and how they're connected together. If your circuit contains a pair of alligator clips, and those alligator clips are intended to connect to either a DC power supply or a battery, then you simply include the alligator clips in your circuit diagram. (I'm not sure what the symbol for those is.) If your circuit contains, say, a pair of alligator clips (to go to a DC power supply) and a battery holder, then you just put both the alligator clips and the battery holder in your diagram; there's probably no need to explicitly show the fact that only one power source will be used at a time.
